# Commercial bank mortgages schedule calculation

Tags: finance, quantlib, finance-mathematics, banks

I need to calculate the schedule of a fixed rate mortgage and an adjustable rate mortgage.

Is there an open source library, preferable in python, that already makes these calculations? I tried `quantlib` but it doesn't support mortgages.

Comment: if you just want to calculate a schedule quantlib can do that, cant it? otherwise `rateslib` has a `Schedule` class which will produce a schedule object for you.

Comment: Or are your talking about the amortised notional amounts. That is a different calculation to just deriving a sequence of dates.

Comment: No, I just need to calculate the payments of a mortgage loan, fixed and variable rates

Comment: I cannot find the schedule class in rateslib, can you point me to where it's documented? thanks

Comment: https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rateslib.scheduling.Schedule.html